# Meteor application not seeding db in deployment

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I have a meteor application which upon startup seeds a mongo db document:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Dynamics.remove({});
  Dynamics.insert({ name : "voteTimer", time : 0 });
  Dynamics.insert({ name : "winningWord", content : "" });
});
```

These are called in a React component eg:

```
getMeteorData() {
  return {
    winningWord: Dynamics.findOne({name: "winningWord"}).content
  }
},
```

On my local machine this works fine. Once deployed via meteor deploy however, the app crashes:
  `Cannot read property 'content' of undefined`

This indicates that there are no documents in the Dynamics collection. Even stranger, I am still able to access these variable in the chrome dev console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you *start* inserting items on startup, those inserts are asynchronous and your component's `getMeteorData` probably still tries to fetch your document before it is inserted. Since `getMeteorData` is reactive (I think), you simply need to check for your findOne to return a proper document and it should work as soon as the document is ready:

```
getMeteorData() {
  var dynamic = Dynamics.findOne({name: "winningWord"});
  if (dynamic) {
    return {
      winningWord: dynamic.content
    }
  }
  return {winningWord:""}; // whatever
},
```